# Rotational Kinetic Energy Conservation

Tags: energy, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

Consider a chain around two gears, one of of radius $r_1$ and the other of $r_2$. Say the gear $r_1$ is attached to a rotational device that delivers torque  $\tau$ . After a quarter cycle of rotation you have input energy $E = \tau\cdot\pi/4$ rotational energy into the system.

Say you have the same system but this time gear $r_2$ is replaced with another gear of radius $r_3$ where $r_3>r_2$. Again you spin it with torque $
\tau$ for a quarter cycle so you have the same energy in the system.

My questions are:

1. Would system 2 (with gear $r_3$) be spinning faster than system 1 (with gear $r_2$)? I think it would since there is a larger gear.
2. If it is spinning faster, how is that justifiable? You input the same energy into both the systems but one is spinning faster than the other.

Thanks for any help.

Edit for clarification:

1. I'm asking about the angular velocity of the first gear in both systems
2. The rotational device is concentrically connected to the first gear

Comment: I have edited the question this time, but in the future please make sure to format all equations and variables using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is it not the opposite? If torque is applied to $r_1$, increasing the radius of the other gear will reduce the second gear angular displacement.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. 1) Which gear are you asking about "spinning faster?" Gear 1 or gear 3? Please edit your question to clarify what you mean. As the question stands, it's unclear. The system is not spinning. Each gear and the "rotational device" are spinning. 2) Time interval of delivery of the torque is also a factor. 3) Also, is the rotational device connected concentrically or edge-to-edge with gear 1

Comment: @BillN The total amount of work done doesn't depend on time if the torque has been specified acting over some angle already. This would just be like how gravity does the same amount of work if you lift a mass one meter over one second or one meter over an hour. Also the entire system has the same linear speed, so you can talk about the speed of the system still.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thanks and noted...will do from now on.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Okay, and 3) is probably unimportant, but my first point stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make some simplifying assumptions here:

1. The gears are much lighter than the chain, so we can assume all of the mass is located on the outside of the gears in the chain itself.
2. The chains wrap all the way around the gear. This is probably less realistic, but this way we can treat the system as two thin hoops that are constrained to spin at the same linear velocity. I don't think this messes up the overall analysis.
3. The chain has a uniform linear mass density $\lambda$.

Therefore, a gear of radius $R$ will have a mass of $m=2\pi R\lambda$ and a moment of inertia of $I=mR^2=2\pi R^3\lambda$ Additionally, given the constraint of the gears being connected by the chain, it must be that the gears have the same linear velocity $v=\omega_1R_1=\omega_2R_2$ at their edges.

The kinetic energy of the two-gear system will then be

$$K=\frac12I_1\omega_1^2+\frac12I_2\omega_2^2=\pi\lambda R_1^2(R_1+R_2)\omega_1^2$$

So as you can see, for the same amount of work, the larger $R_2$ is, the smaller $\omega_1$ will be. Therefore, the larger the second gear the slower everything will rotate.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did a small make-shift experiment with my bike. It seems like the larger (in radius) my rear gear is, the "easier" it is to rotate a quarter cycle. So I can put an F amount of force and move it very fast over 90 degrees. In fact, I must move fast to maintain the force or else the pedal moves away. But as I make my rear gear smaller, it becomes harder. For the roughly same force F over the same quarter cycle distance, I have to move a lot slower. Why do you thing there is this mismatch between the provided answer and the test?

Comment: @A.AK If you really wanted to ask about a bike then you should have done so. Take a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/221070/179151) for more on bikes.

Answer (score 1):

We get the energy equation $$\tau \cdot \theta = \frac {I_1 \omega_1^2}{2} + \frac {I_2 \omega_2^2}{2}$$.

As the two gears are attatched to each other, their linear speed at the edges is same. So, we get the equation $\omega_1 r_1 = \omega_2 r_2$.

Let the moment of inertia of a gear be $I = k m r^2$. Assuming that the gears are made of the same material, their 2-D density - $\sigma$ (mass per unit area) is constant. So, $I = k (\sigma \pi r^2) r^2$, i.e. $I = k' r^4$

Substituting $r_1 = \frac {\omega_2 r_2}{\omega_1}$ and $I_n = k' r_n^4$ in the energy equation, we get
$$ \tau \cdot \theta = \frac {k' \omega_2^2 r_2^2}{2} (r_1^2 + r_2^2)$$
As $\tau \cdot \theta $ is constant in both cases, $$ \omega_2 = \frac {k''}{r_2 \sqrt{r_1^2 + r_2^2}}$$
So, when $r_2$ is increased to $r_3$, it is apparent from the equation that $\omega_2$ will *reduce* to $\omega_3$.

The bigger gear will only spin faster if its density is sufficiently lower than the smaller gear to reduce its moment of inertia.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no other stuff the larger system spins slower due to its larger moment of inertia.

So like the total kinetic energy in the first system assuming a massless chain is given by the angular velocities $\omega_{1,2}$ as $$ K=\frac12 I_1\omega_1^2 +\frac12 I_2\omega_2^2 $$where the moments of inertia are $I_{1,2}.$ The chain between them forces $r_1\omega_1=r_2\omega_2$ when it is taut, so this is $$K =\frac12\left(I_1(r_2/r_1)^2+I_2\right)\omega_2^2$$ and if the gears are of similar construction (same thickness material but pattern otherwise zoomed-in from one size to the other) you'll have $I_1 =(r_1/r_2)^4 I_2$ from dimensional analysis alone, so you will have a rate $$\omega_1=\frac{r_2}{r_1} ~\frac{\tau\cdot\pi/4}{I_2(1+(r_1/r_2)^2)}.$$

So if $s=r_{1,3}/r_2$ you have a term that goes like $1/(s +s^3),$ it decreases as $s$ increases. Bigger systems spin slower with the same energy.

Comment: I get for $\omega_1~$ this equation $\omega_1^2=\frac{2\,\tau\,\pi/4}{I_2\,s^2\,(s^2+1)}$  ???